# How to join a table to the result from a union query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am selecting data from 2 tables using `union select`:

```
select Product_Code from Discount_Table union select Product_Code from Discount2_Table
```

[Union Query returns this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfK5L.png)

[image]

So after I select the data, I want to use this data to join on with other tables, example, Product_Table, but I'm having errors.

This is my query

```
select Product_Name, Price
from Discount_Table
union
select Product_Code
from Discount2_Table
join Product_Table on Discount_Table.Product_Code = Product_Table.Product_Code
```

Any tips/help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use subquery like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 

(select Product_Name,Price from Discount_Table union select Product_Code from Discount2_Table) Discount_Table

JOIN Product_Table ON Discount_Table.Product_Code = Product_Table.Product_Code
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways you can refer to a results table later in a query, but here are a couple:
You can put the results from your first query into a CTE ([Common Table Expression](https://www.essentialsql.com/introduction-common-table-expressions-ctes/)) and then join on that further down in your code:

```
WITH product_codes (Product_code) AS
    (
        select Product_Code 
        from Discount_Table 

        union

        select Product_Code 
        from Discount2_Table 
    )
    select t.Product_Name, t.Price  
    from product_codes pc
    join Product_Table t on pc.Product_Code = t.Product_Code
```

You can also use [temporary tables](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-temporary-tables/):

```
select Product_Code 
INTO #product_codes
from Discount_Table 

union

select Product_Code 
from Discount2_Table 

select t.Product_Name, t.Price  
from #product_codes pc
join Product_Table t on pc.Product_Code = t.Product_Code
```

which works similarly by storing the results from your first query into a temporary table that you can access later on in the query. There are different reasons why you'd choose one version over the other, but they would both work enough to get you results.
I found a nice answer explaining the differences a bit more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19865033/3561222).